# Enabling small caps font in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, core-text, typography

I am trying to enable the small caps feature in a `UILabel`. This question has been asked many times before, and the answer is pretty straightforward:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()

  let fontSize: CGFloat = 24
  let descriptor = UIFont
    .systemFont(ofSize: 24)
    .fontDescriptor
    .addingAttributes([
      UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.featureSettings: [
        UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier: kLowerCaseType,
        UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.featureSettings: kLowerCaseSmallCapsSelector
      ]
    ])

  titleLabel.font = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: fontSize)
  titleLabel.text = "Welcome"
}
```

This code, however, does not work, and I don't understand why. I had a few ideas:

1. The font might not contain the small caps glyphs. I doubt this is the problem since I am using the system font. I tried using "Helvetica Neue" just in case, without success.
2. The small caps fonts are not supported when setting text with the `UILabel.text` property. However, using the `UILabel.attributedText` property instead does not solve the problem.
3. The small caps fonts are not supported by `UILabel` at all. I tried `UITextView`, but the result is the same.
4. This might be an issue with iOS 12, but the problem is reproduced on iOS 11.4 as well.

Is there anything else I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try my code in a fresh project, and it worked. Then I deleted the `titleLabel` from the nib and added a new one, after which my code worked in the current project as well.

It looks like this was either some weird caching issue or some setting on the previous `titleLabel` that was not compatible with small caps fonts.

Answer (score 5):

Having done a few tests, and referring to this Gist (https://gist.github.com/juliensagot/8fc3e2e6b5ad1e14b3ecb394a417b010), it seems that you need to set **BOTH** the upper and lowercase features otherwise small caps doesn't work, at least under iOS 12 in the simulator. Tested with a couple of different fonts.

```
let fontSize: CGFloat = 24.0
let fontDescriptor = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .medium).fontDescriptor

let upperCaseFeature = [
    UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier : kUpperCaseType,
    UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier : kUpperCaseType
 ]

let lowerCaseFeature = [
    UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier : kLowerCaseType,
    UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier : kLowerCaseSmallCapsSelector
]

let features = [upperCaseFeature, lowerCaseFeature]
let additions = fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([.featureSettings: features])

label.font = UIFont(descriptor: additions, size: fontSize)
label.text = "Hello There!"
```

Screenshot from simulator:

[image: Screenshot from the simulator]

Comment: I did some testing and it looks like it is possible to enable small caps for lowercase and uppercase characters separately, and the problem in my case was something else. But anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: Strange, because I created a fresh project, used your code (and other samples) and I couldn't get it to work either...